# How to override width without setting to 100%?

Tags: css, media-queries

How do I override the width of #mydiv in the media query so it is basically 100%?  If I explicitly set it to 100% that will push padding outside of the div, creating horizontally scrolling on a smaller screen.

In Safari Developer Tools style pane, I can uncheck width:800px and everything looks fine at the smaller screen.  How do I translate that into code?  What is the uncheck/toggle doing to *width* in code?

```
#mydiv {
  width:800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width:450px){
  padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: `100%` wont push it outside padding if you apply `box-sizing:border-box;`.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea , that is the answer, publish it ;)

Comment: box-sizing looks to be fairly cross browser compatible as well.  Shouldn't be an issue using it right?

Comment: No it's not. Alternatively, you can use **CSS3 Calc** with `calc(100% - 20px)` where 20px is 10+10 of padding... but box-sizing is the straight way, stick to it ;)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Thanks.  PlantTheldea, so yeah, like Andrea said, publish it as the answer and I'll select.

Comment: He did that five mins ago :>

Comment: Cool.  Stackoverflow didn't show any notification.  Had to refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, publishing:

Simply apply `box-sizing:border-box;` to your CSS for the item, and it will fit `width:100%;` just fine.

As a side note, you should consider applying it to everything at the top of your CSS:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* iOS4, < Android 3.0 */
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

There is a [great article here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) about the many advantages (for one, it works all the way back to IE8). I personally use it on all my projects, never fails me.

Comment: I guess you are using the FF vendor prefix for anything below v19?

Comment: according to their documentation, "There isn't yet a non-prefixed implementation in Gecko." => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbox-sizing, but having it there is also just in case. it doesn't affect performance or execution.

Comment: Ok.  Actually I was wrong - It's all versions of FF that need it: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing.  Didn't notice the prefix in the shaded boxes at first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use box-sizing, however, you could also use any of the following as well:

```
#mydiv {
  width:800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width:450px){
  padding:10px;
  width:auto; /* this will put the width back */
}
```

or

```
#mydiv {
  max-width:800px; /* this will constrain the width to a maximum of 800, but will have a different effect for widths between 800px and 450px */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width:450px){
  padding:10px;
}
```